Would a series representation work for integrating this natural log?
I have the following troublesome integral:
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \ln\Bigg(\frac{\color{red}{r^2}+\color{red}{r_0^2}-2rr_0\cos(\theta_0)}{r^2+\frac{a^4}{r_0^2}-2a^2\frac{r}{r_0}\cos(\theta_0)}\Bigg)d\theta_0$$
Where $r,r_0,a$ are all unspecified constants.
We could also dumb it down to a more general form:
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \ln\Bigg(\frac{a-\color{red}c\cos(\theta_0)}{b-\color{red}d\cos(\theta_0)}\Bigg)d\theta_0$$
if anyone is more comfortable with this representation instead, it shouldn't change how it's solved.
The series representation of $\ln(x) = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(x-1)^n}{n}$ which has a radius of convergence of $x=[0,2]$. I'll approximate this to be $\ln(x) \approx (x-1)$, so our integral would then become:
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \Bigg(\frac{\color{red}{r^2}+\color{red}{r_0^2}-2rr_0\cos(\theta_0)}{r^2+\frac{a^4}{r_0^2}-2a^2\frac{r}{r_0}\cos(\theta_0)} -1\Bigg) d\theta_0$$, right? I'm thinking that because $x = \cos(\theta_0)$, then $x = [-1,1]$ and our radius of convergence is $x=[0,2]$, that this might not work.

Main question is, is the series representation the right way to go?
Subsequent question is, is there anything wrong with my series representation?

EDIT: I forgot to change the integrand to what I had originally intended for it to be. I made the correction in red.

Are you sure the numerator makes sense dimensionally? Moreover, $x$ isn't just the cosine but the whole expression inside the logarithm... I suggest separating it into two logs.

@Conreu Separating into 2 logs would make finding a series representation much simpler. As for the second thing you mentioned, so we want a series representation of a function within a function (or a composite function) i.e. $\ln(\cos(\theta_0))$? And for the first thing you said, I'm not sure what you're getting at, could you clarify what you mean by "dimensionally"?

The argument inside logarithms, exponentials and trig. fucntions have to be adimentional. In your case the numerator has an $r$ and an $r_0$ which are distances summed with a distance squared, $2rr_0\cos\theta_0$. As for the other thing, what I mean is, once separated,
$$\ln(a-b\cos\theta_0)=\ln(a)+\ln\left(1-\dfrac{b}{a}\cos\theta_0\right)$$
and the $2$nd log can be expanded using
$$\ln(1-x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\dfrac{(-x)^n}{n}$$
if and only if $\left|\dfrac{b}{a}\cos\theta_0\right|<1$

@Conreu Thank you!

@YvesDaoust The problem would be the same with or without the index, it's just a consequence of where the problem originates from, though I could have removed it and nothing would have changed

@ResearcherR I'll provide a straightforward computation by using $1$st kind Chebyshev polynomials. This'll be a complementary explanation of what @Quanto means. Note the property
$$\log(1-2xz+z^2)=-2\sum_{n\geq1}\dfrac{\mathrm T_n(x)}{n}z^n,\enspace -1<x<1;\enspace |z|<1$$
In our case $x=\cos\theta_0$ and so
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{2\pi}\log(1-2z\cos\theta_0+z^2)\,\mathrm d\theta_0&=-2\sum_{n\geq1}\int_0^{2\pi}\dfrac{\mathrm T_n(\cos\theta_0)}{n}z^n\,\mathrm d\theta_0\\
&=-2\sum_{n\geq1}\int_0^{2\pi}\dfrac{\cos(n\theta_0)}{n}z^n\,\mathrm d\theta_0=0
\end{aligned}
$$

In light of this, we can now compute your integral easily without recurring to differentiation under the integral sign. This is because your goal integral looks like
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left(\dfrac{a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\theta_0}{c^2+d^2-2cd\cos\theta_0}\right)\,\mathrm d\theta_0$$
which can be separated into
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left(a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\theta_0\right)\,\mathrm d\theta_0-\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left(c^2+d^2-2cd\cos\theta_0\right)\,\mathrm d\theta_0$$
And by factoring either $a^2$ or $b^2$ in the first integral or $c^2$ or $d^2$ in the second such that $|z_1|<1$ and $|z_2|<1$ in
$$\small\int_0^{2\pi}\ln(C_1)\,\mathrm d\theta_0+\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left(1+z_1^2-2z_1\cos\theta_0\right)\,\mathrm d\theta_0-\int_0^{2\pi}\ln(C_2)\,\mathrm d\theta_0-\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left(1+z_2^2-2z_2\cos\theta_0\right)\,\mathrm d\theta_0,$$
then it so follows that
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left(\dfrac{a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\theta_0}{c^2+d^2-2cd\cos\theta_0}\right)\,\mathrm d\theta_0=2\pi\ln\left(\dfrac{C_1}{C_2}\right)$$
That being, there are $4$ situations: $\small \mathbf{1)}\ r>r_0\wedge r>\dfrac{a^2}{r_0}$, $\small \mathbf{2)}\ r>r_0\wedge r<\dfrac{a^2}{r_0}$, $\small \mathbf{3)}\ r<r_0\wedge r>\dfrac{a^2}{r_0}$ and $\small \mathbf{4)}\ r<r_0\wedge r<\dfrac{a^2}{r_0}$. We'll treat the cases where they are equal later.
In situation $\mathbf{1)}$ your goal integral is
$$\small\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left(\dfrac{r^2}{r^2}\cdot\dfrac{1+\dfrac{r_0^2}{r^2}-2\dfrac{r_0}{r}\cos\theta_0}{1+\dfrac{a^4}{r^2r_0^2}-2\dfrac{a^2}{rr_0}\cos\theta_0}\right)\,\mathrm d\theta=0$$
In $\mathbf{2)}$
$$\small\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left(\dfrac{r^2}{\dfrac{a^4}{r_0^2}}\cdot\dfrac{1+\dfrac{r_0^2}{r^2}-2\dfrac{r_0}{r}\cos\theta_0}{1+\dfrac{r^2r_0^2}{a^4}-2\dfrac{rr_0}{a^2}\cos\theta_0}\right)\,\mathrm d\theta=4\pi\ln\left(\dfrac{rr_0}{a^2}\right)$$
In $\mathbf{3)}$
$$\small\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left(\dfrac{r_0^2}{r^2}\cdot\dfrac{1+\dfrac{r^2}{r_0^2}-2\dfrac{r}{r_0}\cos\theta_0}{1+\dfrac{r^2r_0^2}{a^4}-2\dfrac{rr_0}{a^2}\cos\theta_0}\right)\,\mathrm d\theta=4\pi\ln\left(\dfrac{r_0}{r}\right)$$
And in $\mathbf{4)}$
$$\small\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left(\dfrac{r_0^2}{\dfrac{a^4}{r_0^2}}\cdot\dfrac{1+\dfrac{r^2}{r_0^2}-2\dfrac{r}{r_0}\cos\theta_0}{1+\dfrac{r^2r_0^2}{a^4}-2\dfrac{rr_0}{a^2}\cos\theta_0}\right)\,\mathrm d\theta=8\pi\ln\left(\dfrac{r_0}{a}\right)$$
As for the equal cases, we cannot apply the same technique as the series expansion is not analytical when $z=1$. Your integral may then reduce to
$$\small\int_0^{2\pi}\ln(C_1')\,\mathrm d\theta_0+\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left(1-\cos\theta_0\right)\,\mathrm d\theta_0-\int_0^{2\pi}\ln(C_2)\,\mathrm d\theta_0,$$
$$\small\int_0^{2\pi}\ln(C_1)\,\mathrm d\theta_0-\int_0^{2\pi}\ln(C_2')\,\mathrm d\theta_0-\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left(1-\cos\theta_0\right)\,\mathrm d\theta_0,$$
$$\text{or }\small\int_0^{2\pi}\ln(C_1')\,\mathrm d\theta_0-\int_0^{2\pi}\ln(C_2')\,\mathrm d\theta_0.$$
What's clear is that now we need to compute
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left(1-\cos\theta_0\right)\,\mathrm d\theta_0$$
without employing that series expansion. Well, it turns out it isn't too cumbersome since
$$\begin{aligned}
\small\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left(1-\cos\theta_0\right)\,\mathrm d\theta_0&\small=\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left(2\sin^2\left(\frac{\theta_0}{2}\right)\right)\,\mathrm d\theta_0\\
&\small=2\pi\ln(2)+4\int_0^{\pi}\ln(\sin(\theta_0))\,\mathrm d\theta_0\\
&\small=2\pi\ln(2)+4\int_0^{\pi}\left(-\ln(2)-\sum_{k\geq 1}\dfrac{\cos(2k\theta_0)}{k}\right)\,\mathrm d\theta_0\\
&\small=-2\pi\ln(2)
\end{aligned}$$
With that done let's enumerate the rest of possibilities: $\small \mathbf{5)}\ r=r_0\wedge r>\dfrac{a^2}{r_0}$, $\small \mathbf{6)}\ r=r_0\wedge r<\dfrac{a^2}{r_0}$, $\small \mathbf{7)}\ r>r_0\wedge r=\dfrac{a^2}{r_0}$ and $\small \mathbf{8)}\ r<r_0\wedge r=\dfrac{a^2}{r_0}$ and $\small \mathbf{9)}\ r=r_0\wedge r=\dfrac{a^2}{r_0}$.
For $\mathbf{5)}$ we've got
$$\small\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left(\dfrac{2r^2}{r^2}\cdot\dfrac{1-\cos\theta_0}{1+\dfrac{a^4}{r^2r_0^2}-2\dfrac{a^2}{rr_0}\cos\theta_0}\right)\,\mathrm d\theta=0$$
For $\mathbf{6)}$
$$\small\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left(\dfrac{2r_0^2}{\dfrac{a^4}{r_0^2}}\cdot\dfrac{1-\cos\theta_0}{1+\dfrac{r^2r_0^2}{a^4}-2\dfrac{rr_0}{a^2}\cos\theta_0}\right)\,\mathrm d\theta=8\pi\ln\left(\dfrac{r_0}{a}\right)$$
For $\mathbf{7)}$
$$\small\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left(\dfrac{r^2}{2r^2}\cdot\dfrac{1+\dfrac{r_0^2}{r^2}-2\dfrac{r_0}{r}\cos\theta_0}{1-\cos\theta_0}\right)\,\mathrm d\theta=0$$
For $\mathbf{8)}$
$$\small\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left(\dfrac{r_0^2}{2\dfrac{a^4}{r_0^2}}\cdot\dfrac{1+\dfrac{r^2}{r_0^2}-2\dfrac{r}{r_0}\cos\theta_0}{1-\cos\theta_0}\right)\,\mathrm d\theta=8\pi\ln\left(\dfrac{r_0}{a}\right)$$
And finally for $\mathbf{9)}$,
$$\small\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left(\dfrac{2r_0^2}{2r_0^2}\cdot\dfrac{1-\cos\theta_0}{1-\cos\theta_0}\right)\,\mathrm d\theta=0$$
To sum up,
$$\scriptsize\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left(\dfrac{r^2+r_0^2-2rr_0\cos\theta_0}{r^2+\dfrac{a^4}{r_0^2}-2a^2\dfrac{r}{r_0}\cos\theta_0}\right)\,\mathrm d\theta_0=
\left\{\begin{aligned}
& r>r_0: 
\left[\begin{aligned}
& 0,\enspace r>\dfrac{a^2}{r_0}\\
& 0,\enspace r=\dfrac{a^2}{r_0}\\
& 4\pi\ln\left(\dfrac{rr_0}{a^2}\right),\enspace r<\dfrac{a^2}{r_0}\\
\end{aligned}\right.
\\
& r=r_0: 
\left[\begin{aligned}
& 0,\enspace r>\dfrac{a^2}{r_0}\\
& 0,\enspace r=\dfrac{a^2}{r_0}\\
& 8\pi\ln\left(\dfrac{r_0}{a}\right),\enspace r<\dfrac{a^2}{r_0}\\
\end{aligned}\right.
\\
& r<r_0: 
\left[\begin{aligned}
& 4\pi\ln\left(\dfrac{r_0}{r}\right),\enspace r>\dfrac{a^2}{r_0}\\
& 8\pi\ln\left(\dfrac{r_0}{a}\right),\enspace r=\dfrac{a^2}{r_0}\\
& 8\pi\ln\left(\dfrac{r_0}{a}\right),\enspace r<\dfrac{a^2}{r_0}\\
\end{aligned}\right.
\end{aligned}\right\}
=4\pi\max\{\ln(r),\ln(r_0)\}-4\pi\max\{\ln(r),\ln\left(\frac{a^2}{r_0}\right)\}
$$

Thank you for your comprehensive answer! Could you elaborate on where the inequalities are coming from; I don't know exactly how they were worked out? If I factored out $r^2$ from the numerator, my z term is $z=r^2$, then if $|r^2|<1 \rightarrow r<1$, and I'm guessing that the numerator shares this inequality and is less than 1 as well: $$1+\frac{r_0^2}{r^2}-2\frac{r_0}{r}\cos\theta_0 < 1$$ which if true for all $\theta_0$, then picking $\theta_0=0$ $$\frac{r_0^2}{r^2}-2\frac{r_0}{r} < 0\rightarrow r>2r_0 \therefore r >r_0$$ Was this how you did it?

I didn't really do this. It's just like when you want to approximate the Green's function in $3$D using Legendre polynomials. So basically you can expand
$$\dfrac{1}{|\boldsymbol{r-r_0}|}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{r^2+r_0^2-2rr_0\cos(\gamma)}}$$
using
$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-2xt+t^2}}=\sum_{n\geq 0}P_n(x)t^n\enspace \color{red}{|t|<1}.$$
By factoring $r^2$ or $r_0^2$ the Green's function looks like a constant times the Legendre generating function:
$$\dfrac{1}{r\sqrt{1+(r_0/r)^2-2(r_0/r)\cos(\gamma)}}\enspace&\enspace \dfrac{1}{r_0\sqrt{1+(r/r_0)^2-2(r/r_0)\cos(\gamma)}}$$
Since you want $|t|<1$,

then you either have $\left|\dfrac{r_0}{r}\right|<1$ or $\left|\dfrac{r}{r_0}\right|<1$, which translates to $r>r_0$ and $r<r_0$, respectively. You can apply the same reasoning when using the other generating function for $\ln(1-2xz+z^2)$.

Ohhhh okay! Interesting and helpful analogy for future reference as I planned to work through the 3D case next after I've finally parsed through integrating the 2D one. The next step is to integrate with respect to $dr_0$ and now we have our piecewise definitions to integrate over the domain from $r=[0,R]$, so I'll try that next. Thank you!

or $r_0dr_0$ since it's a polar integral. Anyways, if you were interested to see how well the integrand obtained using the other method (integrating the derivative and back integrating) worked out, I did try integrating that result wrt the radial component here to obtain the solution. I know I made a mistake somewhere, but both should work.

That's really nice actually because you'll only have to integrate something like $r_0 f(r_0)\ln(r_0)$

Sorry to bother you one last time, but do you know how we would set up our second integral wrt $r_0dr_0$ given the pair of piecewise definitions for each term? My first attempt had the setup: $$\int_0^R r_0 \ln \frac{f(r,r_0)}{g(r,r_0}dr_0 = \int_0^r r_0 \ln f(r,r_0)dr_0+\int_r^R r_0\ln f(r,r_0)dr_0 - \int_0^{a^2/r} r_0\ln g(r,r_0)dr_0 - \int_{a^2/r}^R r_0\ln g(r,r_0)dr_0 = \pi[2R^2\ln\frac{a}{r} + r^2 - \frac{a^4}{r^2}]$$ where I attributed the different pieces of the domain to $f$ and $g$. Otherwise, not sure how to handle a piecewise definitions given a pair of domain inequalities.

The end result is the same as what I got in my linked question, however recall this result does not satisfy the Poisson Equation, so something is still off here. I also did not include the integration of the terms terms at $r=r_0$ and $r=\frac{a^2}{r_0}$ as I was not sure how to handle integration at a point like this. Would it be like integrating the convolution with a delta function like $\delta(r-r_0)$?

@ResearcherR Let me some time and I'll respond whenever I can.

Take as much time as you need! And I opened up a question about how to set up this a very similar integral HERE if you wanted to reply or even post an answer there instead. I pose the idea of splitting up the discontinuities, but if that isn't possible, I ask about how to set up the bounds of integration. I'll let you decide where you wanna respond though. Thanks and cheers!

Hope all is well! I just wanted to know if you were you still working on this.

@ResearcherR Is it enough if I just find the solution to the Poisson's equation in your other post (assuming that's what you were looking for the whole time)?

Unfortunately, I was looking for how to properly integrate Green's function the whole time. The 2-D case of Poisson's Equation I'm sure could be solved with other methods like say Eigenvalue expansions or taking advantage of the angular symmetry like aruralreader suggests, but I need to use Green's function for a simple 2-D case (in polar coordinates) as practice before moving to the 3-D case of Poisson's Equation (in spherical coordinates) where these other methods don't apply very well in spherical coordinates.

However, if you can arrive to the correct answer (which I don't know) using Green's function, that would be fine

For simplicity,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{2\pi} \ln \left(\frac{b-\cos x}{a-\cos x}\right) d x 
= & \int_0^ {2\pi}\left(\int_a^b \frac{1}{y-\cos x} d y\right) d x \\
= & 2\int_a^b\left( \underbrace{ \int_0^ {\pi}\frac{d x}{y-\cos x}}_{J} \right) d y
\end{aligned}
$$
Noticing that when $ x\mapsto \pi-x, J= \int_0^ {\pi}\frac{d x}{y+\cos x}$ and averaging the two versions yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
J& =\frac{1}{2} \int_0^\pi\left(\frac{1}{y-\cos x}+\frac{1}{y+\cos x}\right) d x \\
& =2 y \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{y^2-\cos ^2 x}\right) d x \\
& =2 y \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sec ^2 x}{y^2 \sec ^2 x-1} d x 
\\& =2 y \int_0^{\infty} \frac{d t}{\left(y^2-1\right)+y^2 t^2}\\&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{y^2-1}}\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{y t}{\sqrt{y^2-1}}\right)\right]_0^{\infty}\\&= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{y^2-1}}
\end{aligned}
$$
Plugging back gives
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \ln \left(\frac{b-\cos x}{a-\cos x}\right) d x 
=2\int_a^b \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{y^2-1}} d y$$
Putting $y=\cosh \theta$, we have
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{2\pi} \ln \left(\frac{b-\cos x}{a-\cos x}\right) d x 
= & 2 \pi \int_{\cosh ^{-1} a}^{\cosh ^{-1}b} \frac{1}{\sinh \theta} \sinh \theta d \theta \\
& =2 \pi\left(\cosh ^{-1}b-\cosh ^{-1}a\right) \\
& =2 \pi\left[\ln \left(b+\sqrt{b^2-1}\right)-\ln \left(a+\sqrt{a^2-1}\right)\right] \\
& =2 \pi \ln \left(\frac{b+\sqrt{b^2-1}}{a+\sqrt{a^2-1}}\right)
\end{aligned}
As @Researcher R noted, replacing $a,b$ by $\frac{a}{c}$ and $\frac{b}{c}$ respectively yields generally
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \ln \left(\frac{b-c\cos x}{a-c\cos x}\right) d x  = 2 \pi \ln \left(\frac{b+\sqrt{b^2-c^2}}{a+\sqrt{a^2-c^2}}\right) $$

And I notice that every step of this still holds for $c = c$. I mistakenly said that the dumbed down (or simpler) form would be for $c=1$, rather it should've been $$\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\Big(\frac{b-c \cos(\theta_0)}{a-c \cos(\theta_0)}\Big)$$. The final answer for $c = c$ would be $$2\pi\ln\bigg(\frac{b+\sqrt{b^2-c^2}}{a+\sqrt{a^2-c^2}}\bigg)$$

Yes, you are right!

Hint
Consider
$$I(c)=\int_0^{2\pi} \log(a-c\cos(x))\,dx \qquad \text{with}\qquad a>1$$
$$I'(c)=-\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos (x)}{a-c \cos (x)}\,dx=\frac{2 \pi }{c} \left(1-\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2-c^2}}\right)$$
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \log(a-\cos(x))\,dx =\int_0^1 I'(c)\,dc=-2 \pi  \log \left(\frac{2
   a}{a+\sqrt{a^2-1}}\right)$$
Do the same for the second logarithm and recombine the results in a single logarithm.

I hope you don't mind if I as a few questions. How did you perform the definite integration of $$-\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos(x)}{a-c\cos(x)}dx$$; this integral itself looks rather involved? Was complex integration used at all by chance?

On the 3rd step, there's a few things I'd like to parse through. 1) the integrand lost the c term, 2) the bound of integration on $I'(c)$ (which performing this integral also looks rather intimidating) is from 0 to 1, is this bc $a>1$ and can c not be negative?, and 3) so the end result is that we've lost x and c, and now everything is in terms of a; 3) isn't so much a question and more I just found it interesting. Is the end result the solution to $I(c)$?

Okay so the second integral looks like you applied partial fraction decomposition and then I'm guessing you applied a technique (I had not seen before) called the Half angle tangent substitution which was used by Euler to solve $$\int_{x_0}^{x_f} \frac{dx}{a+b\cos(x)}$$ but it would be applied to $$a+i^2 b\cos(x)$$, right?

@ClaudeLeibovici I might be wrong but the last result is incorrect (checking computationally). What I got after taking the antiderivative of $I'(c)$ is
$$I(c)=2\pi \tanh^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{a^2-c^2}}{a}\right)+2\pi\log(c)+\text{constant}$$
When you set $c=0$ to determine the constant you get something of the sort
$$2\pi\log(a)=2\pi \tanh^{-1}(\text{sign}(a))+2\pi\log(0)+C$$
which is undetermined. If you take the limit as $c\to 0$, use the log definition of arctanh and use MacLaurin series of $\sqrt{c^2-a^2}$ you'll get the limit depends on the sign of $c$ so the limit $\not\exists$.

@HugdeRoda. What I used is $I(c)=2 \pi  \log \left(a+\sqrt{a^2-c^2}\right)$. For your formula, use $\tanh ^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{2} \log
\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$ and combine the two logarithms to obtain the same result. Moreover, I wrote $a>1$. Cheers :-)

I see, now it is correct since the values coincide numerically up to a constant. Notice though that what you wrote here and in you answer differ as
$$I(c=1)=2\pi\log(a+\sqrt{a^2-1})\neq-2\pi\log\left(\dfrac{2a}{a+\sqrt{a^2-1}}\right)\enspace !$$

@ClaudeLeibovici So I looked into this problem a little more, would this be the Feynman Integration technique?

@ResearcherR. Yes, it is !

Putting together what I've seen across different answer, I decided to piece together my own answer using an amalgamation of different workings I've seen.
Splitting up the natural log:
$$\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\Big(\frac{a^2}{r_0^2}\frac{r^2+r_0^2-2rr_0\cos\theta_0}{r^2+\frac{a^4}{r_0^2}-2\frac{r}{r_0}a^2\cos\theta_0}\Big) = \frac{1}{4\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\Big(\frac{a_1}{a_2}\frac{b_1-c_1\cos\theta_0}{b_2-c_2\cos\theta_0}\Big)d\theta_0 \\ = \frac{1}{4\pi}\Bigg[\underbrace{\int_0^{2\pi}\Big(\ln(a_1)+\ln(b_1-c_1\cos\theta_0)\Big)d\theta_0}_{(1)}-\underbrace{\int_0^{2\pi}\Big(\ln(a_2)-\ln(b_2-c_2\cos\theta_0)\Big)d\theta_0}_{(2)}\Bigg]$$
Starting with (1) by following from Claude's setup:
$$\cases{I(b_1,c_1) = \int_0^{2\pi}\ln(b_1-c_1\cos\theta_0)d\theta_0
 \\
I'(b_1,c_1) = \frac{\partial}{\partial c_1} I(b_1,c_1)}
\\
\text{We'll also use: }\int_0^c I'(b_1,c_1)dc_1 = I(b_1,c_1) - I(b_1,0) \rightarrow I(b_1,c_1) = I(b_1,0) + \int_0^c I'(b_1,c_1)dc 
 \\ 
\text{And we can change the order of integration if we replace $c_1$ with a dummy variable : }
\\I(b_1,c_1) = I(b_1,0) + \int_0^{2\pi} \Big(\int_0^c \frac{\partial}{\partial x'} f(b_1,x',\theta_0) dx' \Big)d\theta_0 = I(b_1,0) + \int_0^c \int_0^{2\pi} f(b_1,x',\theta_0)_{x'} d\theta_0 dx'$$
Solving the double integral can be done via half-angle tan substitution:
$$I(b_1,c_1) = \int_0^c \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\cos\theta_0}{x'\cos\theta_0-b_1}d\theta_0 dx' \\ = \int_0^c\Bigg(-\frac{b_1}{x'}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{(b_1-x')+(b_1+x')t^2}dt + \frac{2\pi}{x'}\Bigg)dx' \\ 
= \int_0^c\Bigg(-\frac{b_1}{x'(b_1+x')}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{2dt}{\frac{b_1-x'}{b_1+x'}+t^2}dt + \frac{2\pi}{x'}\Bigg)dx' \\
= \int_0^c\Bigg(-\frac{2b_1}{x'\sqrt{b_1^2-x'^2}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{1+\Bigg(\frac{t}{\sqrt{\frac{b_1-x'}{b_1+x'}}}\Bigg)^2}dt + \frac{2\pi}{x'}\Bigg)dx' \\
=\boxed{2\pi\int_0^c \frac{1}{x'}-\frac{b_1}{x'\sqrt{b_1^2-x'^2}}dx'}$$
where we've used polynomial division to turn $\frac{\cos\theta_0}{c_1\cos\theta_0-b_1} = \frac{1}{x'}-\frac{b_1}{x'(b_1-x'\cos\theta_0)}$ prior to integrating to make the integrand a little easier to work with.
The next step is to then integrate $2\pi\int_0^c \frac{1}{x'}-\frac{b_1}{x'\sqrt{b_1^2-x'^2}}  dx'$ which can be done using simple substitution:
$$2\pi\int_0^c \frac{1}{x'^2}\Bigg(1-\frac{b_1}{\sqrt{b_1^2-x'^2}}\Bigg) x'dx' \\
u^2 = b_1^2-x^2, -udu = x'dx \\ 
= -2\pi\int_{b_1}^\sqrt{b_1^2-c^2} \frac{1}{(b_1^2-u^2)}\Bigg(1-\frac{b_1}{u}\Bigg) udu \\ 
= 2\pi\int_{b_1}^\sqrt{b_1^2-c^2} \frac{1}{(b_1+u)(b_1-u)}\Bigg(b_1-u\Bigg) udu \\
v = b_1+x', dv = dx' \\ 
2\pi\int_{2b_1}^{b_1+\sqrt{b_1^2-c^2}} \frac{dv}{v} \\ 
= 2\pi\ln\Bigg(\frac{b_1+\sqrt{b_1^2-c^2}}{2b_1}\Bigg)$$
Now subtract off $I(b_1,0) = \int_0^{2\pi} ln(b_1) d\theta_0$
$$\boxed{I(b_1,c_1) = 2\pi\ln\Bigg(\frac{b_1+\sqrt{b_1^2-c_1^2}}{2}\Bigg)}
 \\
\boxed{I(b_2,c_2) = 2\pi\ln\Bigg(\frac{b_2+\sqrt{b_2^2-c_2^2}}{2}\Bigg)}$$
And combining the natural logs together:
$$\frac{1}{2}\Bigg(\frac{a_1}{a_2}\frac{\frac{b_1+\sqrt{b_1^2-c_1^2}}{2}}{\frac{b_2+\sqrt{b_2^2-c_2^2}}{2}}\Bigg)$$
Just cancel out the 2s and:
$$I(b_1,c_1,b_2,c_2) = \frac{1}{2}\ln\Bigg(\frac{a_1}{a_2}\frac{b_1+\sqrt{b_1^2-c_1^2}}{b_2+\sqrt{b_2^2-c_2^2}}\Bigg)$$

Below is going to be a way to rewrite this result so that it becomes significantly easier for subsequent integration:
Rewriting this is in terms of $r$, $a$, and $r_0$:
$$-\frac{1}{2}\ln\Bigg(\frac{a^2}{r_0^2}\frac{r^2+\frac{a^4}{r_0^2}+\sqrt{\Big(r^2+\frac{a^4}{r_0^2}\Big)^2-4\Big(\frac{r}{r_0}a^2\Big)^2}}{r^2+r_0^2+\sqrt{(r^2+r_0^2)^2-4(rr_0)^2}}\Bigg)
\\
= -\frac{1}{2}\ln\Bigg(\frac{a^2}{r_0^2}\frac{r^2+\frac{a^4}{r_0^2}+\sqrt{\Big(r^4+2r^2\frac{a^4}{r_0^2}+a^4(\frac{a}{r_0})^4\Big)-4\Big(\frac{r}{r_0}a^2\Big)^2}}{r^2+r_0^2+\sqrt{(r^4+2r^2r_0^2+r_0^4)-4(rr_0)^2}}\Bigg)
\\
= -\frac{1}{2}\ln\Bigg(\frac{a^2}{r_0^2}\frac{r^2+\frac{a^4}{r_0^2}+\sqrt{r^4+a^4(\frac{a}{r_0})^4-2\Big(\frac{r}{r_0}a^2\Big)^2}}{r^2+r_0^2+\sqrt{r^4+r_0^4-2(rr_0)^2}}\Bigg) 
\\ 
=-\frac{1}{2}\ln\Bigg(\frac{a^2}{r_0^2}\frac{r^2+\frac{a^4}{r_0^2}+\sqrt{\Big(r^2-a^2(\frac{a}{r_0})^2\Big)^2}}{r^2+r_0^2+\sqrt{\Big(r^2-r_0^2\Big)^2}}\Bigg) 
\\ 
=-\frac{1}{2}\ln\Bigg(\frac{a^2}{r_0^2}\frac{r^2+\frac{a^4}{r_0^2}+|(r)^2-\Big(\frac{a^2}{r_0}\Big)^2|}{r^2+r_0^2+|(r)^2-(r_0)^2|}\Bigg)$$
$$\boxed{I(r,r_0) = -\frac{1}{2}\ln\Bigg(\frac{r_0^2}{a^2}\frac{r^2+\frac{a^4}{r_0^2}+|r^2-\Big(\frac{a^2}{r_0}\Big)^2|}{r^2+r_0^2+|r^2-(r_0)^2|}\Bigg)}$$

The integral vanishes per $\int_0^\pi \ln\left(1+2b\cos \theta+b^2\right)d\theta=0$
\begin{align}
I
=\int_0^{2\pi} \ln\frac{1-2\frac{r_0}{r}\cos\theta+ \frac{r^2_0}{r^2}}{1-2\frac{a^2}{r r_0}\cos\theta+ \frac{a^4}{r^2 r^2_0}}d\theta
=0
\end{align}

I'm so sorry, I messed up and forgot to change the integrand to what I had originally intended for it to be. It was supposed to be $$\frac{\color{red}{r^2+r_0^2}-2rr_0\cos\theta_0}{r^2+\frac{a^4}{r_0^2}-2a^2\frac{r}{r_0}\cos\theta_0}$$. Also, if the result is $p_+^2$, I don't think $\pm$ would be in the final result, would it? Oh and $\frac{r+r_0}{\color{red}{2}}$, the 2 is missing, or did it go somewhere else? I'm sure if I parsed through this it would work just fine for this integrand though. Sorry for screwing that up!

@ResearcherR - It ‘s much simpler then.
